# ruby require_relative gives LoadError: cannot infer basepath inside IRB

Tags: ruby, require

I am currently in

```
Dropbox/96_2013/work/ror/dmc/dmStaffing/QA/selenium_server_wyatt/spec/2day/units/
```

I can go into irb and require a file but it's a really long require...

```
require '/home/durrantm/Dropbox/96_2013/work/ror/dmc/dmStaffing/QA/selenium_server_wyatt/spec/2day/units/login_as_admin_spec.rb'
=> true
```

I want to use require_relative, as in

```
$ cd /home/durrantm/Dropbox/96_2013/work/ror/dmc/dmStaffing/QA/selenium_server_wyatt/spec/2day/
$ pwd
/home/durrantm/Dropbox/96_2013/work/ror/dmc/dmStaffing/QA/selenium_server_wyatt/spec/2day
$ irb
irb(main):001:0> require_relative 'units/login_as_admin_spec.rb'
```

but I get:

```
LoadError: cannot infer basepath
```

Comment: There has been some discussion about that at: https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/4487

Answer (score 32, accepted):

`require_relative` requires a file relative to the file the call to `require_relative` is in. Your call to `require_relative` isn't in any file, it's in the interactive interpreter, therefore it doesn't work.

You can use the long form of `require` by explicitly passing the full path:

```
require './units/login_as_admin_spec.rb'
```

Or you add the current directory to the `$LOAD_PATH` and just `require` as usual:

```
$LOAD_PATH << '.'
require 'units/login_as_admin_spec'
```

Answer (score 6):

This is a known bug in ruby:

- [Ruby bug #4487: require_relative fails in an eval'ed file](http://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/4487)

If you are using Pry, instead of IRB, this can be fixed by installing the [pry-require_relative gem](https://github.com/envygeeks/pry-require_relative).

```
gem install pry-require_relative
```

Answer (score 4):

This worked:

```
require File.expand_path("../login_as_admin_spec.rb", __FILE__)
```

Comment: Which Ruby version are you on?

Comment: If you run just `File.expand_path("../login_as_admin_spec.rb", __FILE__)` you should see `__FILE__` get's ignored and you get the full path of just like `File.expand_path("./login_as_admin_spec.rb")`

Answer (score 2):

`require_relative` works in the context of the current source file. This is different than the current working directory. I don't believe `irb` or `pry` have an understanding of "this current source file" concept; since you're not actually in a file.

In these [REPLs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read%E2%80%93eval%E2%80%93print_loop), just use a relative path reference `require './units/login_as_admin_spec.rb'`.

Comment: didn't work, couldn't find file, tried `./units`, `units`, `../units` and none worked.

Comment: @MichaelDurrant what was the error and the line of code you typed? It does work, I've done it multiple times.

Comment: pry does, see @gawin's comment, above.