# Dynamic require_relative in test_helper not working

Tags: ruby

I've been battling for an hour with a `require_relative` in my `test_helper.rb` that I just can't seem to get to work.

Given a project structure like so

```
lib
 |-- square_digits.rb
test
 |-- test_square_digits.rb
 |-- test_helper.rb
```

And these test files:

```
# test/test_square_digits.rb
require 'test_helper'

# test/test_helper.rb
require "minitest/autorun"
Dir.glob('../lib/**/*.rb').each { |f| require_relative f }

# require_relative "../lib/square_every_digit.rb"
```

I cannot get my tests to run correctly with the dynamic require, but directly requiring with the hardcoded path does function as intended, though the `Dir.glob` does seem to catch the file (while running pry in test/)

```
$ pry(main)> Dir.glob('../lib/**/*.rb')
$ => ["../lib/square_every_digit.rb"]
```

I have tried the [require_relative gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/require_relative/versions/1.0.3), `Dir[]` and various solutions to no avail...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried generating the lines of code and using `eval`

```
baseDir = __dir__+"/RGSS Classes"
fileCol = Dir.children(baseDir) 

fileCol.each do |library|
    libPath = baseDir+"/"+library
    code = "require '"+libPath+"'"
    puts code
    eval(code)
end
```

you wont be able to use `require_reletive` because it'll give a *"LoadError: cannot infer basepath"*, i am unsure if it's the same reason as stated in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16428511/1028804) but using `require` worked

first need to get the current file location using `__dir__` and then append whatever subfolder the files you want to require are. then you loop though the results generating the line of code for each file (i choose to generate the path in a variable first before adding it to the code)

obviously since `eval` is executing string as code if this is used outside of ***personal private use*** you'd might want to add some sanitization to the file names as a bad or maliciously named file will execute as code.

alternatively you can forgo using `eval` and have it output each line to a .rb file which you would then `require` which eliminates the risk of filenames being used to inject code